# drop down menu updates inner HTML when changed, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have drop down menus, the last 2 are price and tickets which then makes a calculation and shows the total amount on screen when selected.  It works fine although if i change the selection to a different price the total does not update.  Also the same idea applies to the part where the user selects 4 or more tickets and an message appears on screen.  Im sure its something simple but i cant seem to figure it out.

I have attached a Jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dwdqg/

```
function totalPrice(ticketCount,priceAmount)
{           
    if (tickets.selectedIndex != 0 && price.selectedIndex != 0)  // if the price and tickets is not 0 or not selected
    {                       
        tickets.onchange = ticketCount;  //when tickets is changed assign the index to var ticketCount

        price.onchange = priceAmount;

        var ticketCount = tickets.value;  //get the value of ticketCount index

        var priceAmount = price.value;

        var totalPrice = (ticketCount * priceAmount);       

        document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = ("Total Price £" + totalPrice);           

    }


    if (ticketCount >= 4)  // if ticketCount is 4 or more
    {
        totalPrice = totalPrice + 10;  // add on 10 to the price

        document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = ("Total Price £" + totalPrice);

        document.getElementById("moreTickets").innerHTML = ("Buying four or more tickets will add an additional £10 fee.")

    }   


}
```

Comment: This is not about your question, but I must say it. You should really generalize your code. It's way too repetitive. Use functions, and data structures instead of just repeating blocks of code with tiny variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `totalPrice` in your change handlers.

For example:

```
price.onchange = function()
  // totalPrice needs to be called
}
```

You've attached it here

```
<select name="tickets" id="tickets" onChange="totalPrice(tickets)" style="width:120px">
```

However, that only responds to changes to number of tickets. You haven't attached it to the other elements.

Also - your onchange only fires once because you're replacing the option fields using `fillList` after the change event fires. You can either reattach the handler or have it respond to a `click` event.

With that said - I don't recommend attaching handlers as HTML attributes and I suggest cleaning up your code to be more readable.

Comment: In addition, your onChange is only firing once... you probably want to respond to onClick as well. That's the reason when you re-pick the number of tickets you want doesn't update the price.